# My Database may have been affected by Shoplift vulnerability (SUPEE-5344)

Tags: security, supee-5344

I am trying to see all worst case scenario. My one of the site may have been shoplifted.

Now, I am in process of quarantine it first then start fresh site with fresh files.

However, I do need current database.

**My main qst**

1. Reported `Shoplift` or any other vulnerability on Magento would have infected the database?
2. How to quarantine DB? I have got really large DB.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I ounce saw a shoplifted site that had admin accounts, PayPal account, bank transfer settings so database surely is affected in core_config and users tables.

If you start fresh I suggest migrate only orders customers categories products and generally no config (keep reviews, tags etc. )

Of course keep your encryption key, we don't want the customers can't login and everyone have to use password reminder.

As a precaution change ftp and admin password.